# May I know is there a flutter package to do markups and annotations on photos and drawings?

Tags: flutter, markup, flutter-packages

Annotations and markups such as adding text, shapes, drawings arrows, rotate etc

Comment: cant understand your issue explain more and add some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what your design intentions are or if there is a plugin to fit them but I can recommend you use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget which allows you to place multiple items on the z axis (on top of each other) and then place the image or drawing in the background and overlay your markup using the [markup plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/markup_text) or [markdown plugin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for markdown.

So something like;

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container( // Replace this container with your image.
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    MarkupText( // Replace this text with your markup.
      "This is a (b)bold(/b) text (a http://flutter.dev)with a link(/a),"
      " an (u)underlined(/u) word (a http://pub.dev)with"
      " a second link containing a word in (i)italics(/i)(/a) and (c #ff0000)colored(/c) words"
      " (c deepPurpleAccent)here(/c) and (c green)there(/c).",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    ),
  ],
)
```